# Define Array Values with Variables with php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am using `$_POST` to post data to a php file. In that php file, I have the following.

```
$params = array(
        'name' => "$fname",
        'email' => "$email",
        'ad_tracking' => 'test',
        'ip_address' => '$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]',
    );
    $subscribers = $list->subscribers;
    $new_subscriber = $subscribers->create($params);
```

What is the best way to use the `$_POST` data to define the vales of each keys in the array?
The use of `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is also not working as hoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST variables are passed via the super global array `$_POST` in PHP. So in your case, this would technically work:

```
$params = array(
    'name' => $_POST['fname'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'ad_tracking' => 'test',
    'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
);
```

Your code for `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` was enclosed in single quotes, which in PHP means a verbatim string (i.e. without variable interpolation).

Btw, you should think of input filtering too - http://www.php.net/filter

To give you an example, this would perform input filtering in your current case:

```
$filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, array(
    'fname' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'email' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
);
```

Each value inside `$filtered` will either have a value (valid), be `NULL` (not present) or `false` (invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "the use of $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] is also not working as hoped.":
Single-Quotes don't evaluate php variables

```
$params = array(
    'name' => $_POST["fname"],
    'email' => $_POST["email"],
    'ad_tracking' => 'test',
    'ip_address' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
);
$subscribers = $list->subscribers;
$new_subscriber = $subscribers->create($params);
```

Comment: This is my code: https://justpaste.it/1gt46. How can i declare more than one id's in variable. Single value declaration is : $productId = 19;   How can i declare more than one value in $productId=?